# Translate CVK from LMK reference to ZMK reference in THALES9000

Tags: hsm

I am trying to translate a CVK from LMK reference to ZMK reference in order to deliver it to an external party to be imported at their side.

I tried to do this using a console command like below:

Firstly, I used the KA command to generate the encrypted CVKA & CVKB.
I then tried  KB command to translate  these keys to ZMK reference. I got an error "invalid data" .

```
<KB> 
Enter encrypted CVK A: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX 
Enter encrypted CVK B: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX 
Enter encrypted ZMK: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
```

I tried the same using host command like below:

```
send 0001AU + ******************** + **************** / ****************
(send 0001AU) + (ZMK Encrypted under LMK) + (CVKA/B that i got from KA/KB console command).
```

I got response 15 (invalid input data).

Am I using wrong inputs in the above commands?

Answer (score 0):

KA and KB are legacies commands. Try to use KE to export your CVK.

Comment: is the below the correct steps for doing this ?
Online-AUTH> KE <Return> 
Enter Key type: 402 <Return> 
Enter Key Scheme: Z <Return> 
Enter ZMK: U XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX --> Encrypted ZMK here 
Enter key: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX --> CVKA or CVKB that i got from KA command

Comment: I have used the below host command for exporting CVK :
send     Key Export Command + KEY TYPE for CVK + CVK (i got from KA console command)  
send 0001 + A8 + 402 + XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX + XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX + Z

I got response code 15 (invalid data),am i using a wrong inputs here also ?

Comment: 0001 + A8 + 402 + U + XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX + XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX + Z

Comment: same as well :(

Comment: any more help for what could be a reason of the encryption failure ?!

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a screenshot of your data.

Answer (score 0):

if you use KA and KB commands make sure to use also an encrypted ZMK. this works for me:

1. encrypt your ZMK components with "**Z**" command (do it for all your components)
2. generate enc. ZMK with "**D**" command (provide it the output from step 1)
3. generate your CVK pair with "**KA**" command
4. export CVK keys with "**KB**" command (use output of step 2 and 3)

good luck :)